# Image not scalable on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this image that you can enlarge in mobile view:

[image]

However the user can't pinch-zoom/move around to see the image outside of the viewport.

Does anyone have a suggestion to fix this?

Here is the page to test: https://offsideornot.com/offside/west-bromwich-albion-vs-southamption_WfPbYBUvZlhDPvN4lp1x

I thought adding `user-scalable=yes` here `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes"/>` would help but it doesnt.

Comment: I can pinch/zoom and move around the image on an iPad, but I'm not sure what you mean by 'outside the viewport'.

Comment: Well to the left and right of the viewport there is more of the image but you cant like move the image over to see it.

Comment: Ah, got it - you've got a large image, only a bit is showing and you want the user to be able to move it around to see any of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest example I can think of is to let the image take its 'natural' dimensions but have it in a container that is smaller - i.e. don't do any of the normal things like have object-fit: cover or contain. In that way the user can get the best definition that is available, can move the image within its container and can zoom.

Of course, for the actual webpage, without the user interacting with the image, you may want more of the image to show in the 'static' state. I don't know exactly what the requirement is. On a small device perhaps giving the user the option of using the whole screen to view the image (before zooming it) might be possible as this use (spot the ball) needs as clear definition as possible.

Here's the simple snippet to get things started:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 50px;
}
img {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxX4s.jpg" />
</div>
```